# Alternative to partial(nonaggregated column) in group by [Ollivander's Inventory problem on hackerrank]

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to solve https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/harry-potter-and-wands/problem

With proper mysql setup one can do following

```
select w.id, wp.age, min(w.coins_needed), w.power from wands w
join wands_property wp
on wp.code = w.code and wp.is_evil=0
group by w.code
order by w.power desc, wp.age desc;
```

But hackerrank's mysql setup does not allow partial grouping. It throws error

> SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column 'run_eootvjd0lna.w.id' which is not functionally dependent on
>   columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

So I would like to first filter out all the duplicates for a given code in `wands` table and only leave rows having minimum coins_needed. This way I can then join `wands_property` on the extracted table.

Would like to get suggestion on extraction of only relevant minimum coins_needed rows, so that it can be used further on.

PS: I have created a sqlfiddle with sample data [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6365a0/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my ***Explaination*** of the solution (final solution in ***step 3***):

***Step 1:***

Filter rows with minimum coins needed based on power & code.
Why code & power because requirement wants us to filter based on age and power  and age has 1-1 relationship with code so code and power are logical places to filter

```
select w2.code, w2.power, min(w2.coins_needed) coins
from wands w2
group by w2.code, w2.power
```

***Step 2:***

Use this table with only filtered rows to get all the columns of wands table

```
select w.id, wp.age, w.code, min(w.coins_needed), w.power  from wands w
join (
        select w2.code, w2.power, min(w2.coins_needed) coins from wands w2
        group by w2.code, w2.power
      ) wcp
on wcp.code = w.code and wcp.power = w.power and wcp.coins = w.coins_needed
```

***Step 3:***

**Final step** is to join with wands_property with the new table we got in step 2 and order it as required by the problem

```
select w.id, wp.age, w.code, min(w.coins_needed), w.power  from wands w
join (
        select w2.code, w2.power, min(w2.coins_needed) coins from wands w2
        group by w2.code, w2.power
      ) wcp
on wcp.code = w.code and wcp.power = w.power and wcp.coins = w.coins_needed
join wands_property wp
on wp.code = w.code and wp.is_evil=0
order by w.power desc, wp.age desc ;
```

Answer (score 1):

@katch I think in the first "SELECT" statement you don't need to use min on coins_needed since min is already applied in the subquery to filter only smallest coins_needed for same code and power, I executed this code and it was accepted as the correct answer
`` SELECT w.id, p.age, w.coins_needed, w.`power` FROM Wands w INNER JOIN (SELECT w1.code, w1.power, min(w1.coins_needed) as coins FROM Wands w1 GROUP BY code, power) AS  w2 ON w.code = w2.code AND w.coins_needed = w2.coins AND w.`power` = w2.`power` INNER JOIN Wands_Property p ON w.code = p.code WHERE p.is_evil = 0 ORDER BY w.`power` DESC, p.age DESC ``

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i got it right

But with

```
select w.id, w.code, w2.coins_needed, w.power
, wp.age 
from wands w
inner join (SELECT code, Min(coins_needed) coins_needed From Wands Group by code)  w2 
on w.code = w2.code and w.coins_needed = w2.coins_needed
join wands_property wp
on wp.code = w.code and wp.is_evil=0
```

You get

```
id  code    coins_needed    power   age
1   10      100             2       100
3   20      300             3       200
8   40      300             4       400
```

This is the result for all wands that cost minimum for every code that is not evil with out grouping it.