# Hackerrank Challenge Ollivander's Inventory

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi the link the the question is here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/harry-potter-and-wands/problem

My solution is very simple as below. Logic is that **"group by power and age"** should give me minimum coins for every power-age combination. 
Please tell me what am I missing.

```
select m.id, m.age, min(m.coins_needed) as coins_needed, m.power
from (
select w.*, wp.age
from wands as w
inner join wands_property as wp
on w.code = wp.code
where is_evil != 1
order by w.power desc, wp.age desc, w.coins_needed asc
) m
group by m.power, m.age
order by m.power desc, m.age desc;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was my previously submitted (accepted) solution in MS SQL Server, but this much should be the same for MySQL.

```sql
SELECT
    W.id,
    WP.age,
    W.coins_needed,
    W.power
FROM Wands W
INNER JOIN Wands_Property WP ON W.code = WP.code
WHERE WP.is_evil != 1
AND W.coins_needed = (
    SELECT
        MIN(W2.coins_needed)
    FROM Wands W2
    INNER JOIN Wands_Property WP2 ON W2.code = WP.code
    WHERE WP2.age = WP.age
    AND W2.power = W.power)
ORDER BY
    W.power DESC,
    WP.age DESC
```

You need to find the minimum coins separately and then find who has those coins.

---

For your code, you're not doing the inner join with `WHERE WP.age = P.age`, that should reduce your unnecessary rows, but you'll still have an issue with getting the value of the coins.

---

It seems MySQL supports partial `GROUP BY`s but HackerRank's platform is not yet set up for that. Look into [this (original) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58329024) for explanation and a slightly different solution.

Comment: Hi @AjitZero I would recommend to change alias from inner select of a table Wands 
 into w1 or something else that is different from w because you use it one time before and in this case : `AND W.power = W.power` is no good. Also change this part  `MIN(Wands.coins_needed)` into something like this: `MIN(w.coins_needed)`  = put the right alias

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll add the last working code instead. this doesn't work. I was renaming it from my older code.

Answer (score 1):

I've been recently working through these problems to brush up on my MySQL.  This was the solution I came up with, which follows similar logic to the prior posts in this thread.  Basically, all I'm trying to do here is find the minimally-priced non-evil wands per code and power (and redundantly, age).

Then, I apply an inner join to only return those wands of the same wand code and price as the minimally-priced ones.  Finally, I sort by whatever the problem asked for (power and age, DESC).

As long as you're applying similar logic to your code, you should be able to get it to work.

Cheers.

```
SELECT wands.id, h.age, h.min_coins, h.power
FROM(
    SELECT wands.code, p1.age, min(wands.coins_needed) AS min_coins, wands.power
        FROM wands
            JOIN Wands_Property as p1
                ON wands.code = p1.code
            WHERE p1.is_evil != 1
            GROUP BY wands.code, p1.age, wands.power) AS h
INNER JOIN wands
     ON h.min_coins = wands.coins_needed and h.code = wands.code
ORDER BY h.power DESC, h.age DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanna add another coding way to solve the challenge.
My code logic is simple:

1. Create a virtual table contains wands which is not evil and has the min price (because some wands has the same code, age and power, but got a different price and id)

```
SELECT
   w.code,
   wp.age,
   MIN(w.coins_needed) as mincoin,
   w.power
FROM
   wands AS w
LEFT JOIN wands_property AS wp
   ON w.code = wp.code
WHERE
   wp.is_evil = 0
GROUP BY
   w.code,
   wp.age,
   w.power
```

2. Join the virtual table with the wands table, then order them according to the requirements
   Here is my code solution:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    b.age,
    b.mincoin,
    b.power
FROM wands AS a
JOIN    (
        SELECT
            w.code,
            wp.age,
            MIN(w.coins_needed) as mincoin,
            w.power
        FROM
            wands AS w
        LEFT JOIN wands_property AS wp
            ON w.code = wp.code
        WHERE
            wp.is_evil = 0
        GROUP BY
            w.code,
            wp.age,
            w.power
        ) AS b
        ON  a.code = b.code and a.coins_needed = b.mincoin
ORDER BY
    b.power DESC,
    b.age DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL

1. Find the minimum coins required where the code(age) and the power remain the same.
2. Select the previously created selection and join the wands table using both minimum coin required and code.
3. Join the wands_property table using code.
4. modify the select statement with the relevant column names and order it.

```
SELECT w.id, wp.age, gg.gold, w.power
FROM (SELECT code, MIN(coins_needed) as gold
FROM wands 
GROUP BY code, power)gg
INNER JOIN wands AS w
ON gg.gold = w.coins_needed AND gg.code = w.code
INNER JOIN wands_property AS wp
ON wp.code = w.code
WHERE wp.is_evil = 0
ORDER BY w.power DESC, wp.age DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution(accepted)(MS SQL Server) for this one is using ROW_NUMBER() function which will give you a rank for every unique combination of highest power with age and with coins needed in the increasing rank.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.age, t1.coins_needed, t1.power 
FROM(
SELECT Wands.id, Wands_Property.age, Wands.coins_needed, Wands.power, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY power,age ORDER BY Wands.power desc, Wands_Property.age desc, coins_needed) AS Ranks
FROM Wands_Property 
INNER JOIN Wands on Wands_Property.code=Wands.code and Wands_Property.is_evil=0) as t1 
where t1.Ranks=1
order by power desc, age desc
```

---

For your code, you are just filtering the minimum coins_needed for the highest power and age of wand instead of selecting the entire row which consists minimum coins for wand.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,age, coins_needed, power 
from
(select id,age, coins_needed, power,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(partition by age, power order by coins_needed ) as d_rank
from wands w
JOIN wands_property wp on w.code = wp.code
 where is_evil = 0
 ) as min_coins
 where d_rank = 1
 order by power desc, age desc
```

If you are looking for a shorter solution use the `DENSE_RANK` window function. I am doing the following:

- Ranking based on (age,power) pairs and ordering by the number of coins needed which puts the minimum coins needed at the top of each partition with a rank of 1. I am using `DENSE_RANK` as opposed to `RANK` because of the possibility of there being wands with the same age power and coins needed.
- Ordering results by power, and if more than one wand has the same power order by age in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  w.id, 
  wp.age, 
  i.coins_needed, 
  i.power 
FROM 
  (
    select 
      wp.age, 
      w.power, 
      min(w.coins_needed) as coins_needed 
    from 
      wands w 
      inner join wands_property wp on w.code = wp.code 
    where 
      wp.is_evil = 0 
    group by 
      wp.age, 
      w.power
  ) i 
  inner join wands w on i.coins_needed = w.coins_needed 
  and i.power = w.power 
  inner join wands_property wp on i.age = wp.age 
  and w.code = wp.code 
order by 
  i.power desc, 
  wp.age desc
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select id,age,coins_needed, power from(
    select id,age,coins_needed, power, rank() over(partition by age,power order by 
   coins_needed) rr
    from wands w
    left join wands_property wp
    on w.code=wp.code
    where is_evil=0)a
where rr=1
order by power desc,age desc
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The comment isn't visually explained.

Kindly check [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to proper write your answer.